# MediaWiki Semantic Template: Property "" (as page type) with input value contains invalid characters or is incomplete can cause unexpected results

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73349623/196210) I've created a template which mix a visual representation and populates a semantic one.

[I've used the template in a page](https://www.tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Tutti_gli_articoli_di_Marco_Crepaldi) but *the last part* doesn't work and returns the following message.

```
Property "" (as page type) with input value "psicologia|governo|politica|lavoro|+sep=|" contains invalid characters or is incomplete and therefore can cause unexpected results during a query or annotation process.
```

**The template:**

```
[{{{url}}} {{{title}}}] - {{{categories}}} 
{{#subobject:
|url = {{{url}}}
|title = {{{title}}}
|@category={{{categories}}}
}}
```

**The desired behaviour:**

```
{{#subobject:
|url = https://www.instagram.com/p/CXeE2j-NT6s/
|title = Bullismo: proposta una legge in Francia per punirlo penalmente. Si rischia anche il carcere
|@category=bullismo|violenza|leggi|punizioni|+sep=|
}}
```

Comment: Don't use pipe as separator for your category list.

Comment: @IRA1777 I've tried 4 or 5 settings here but still not working tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Tutti_gli_articoli_di_Marco_Crepaldi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use | as a separator, it will not recognize it as a separator, try a comma, a hyphen or something that you generally don't use in Mediawiki coding

Comment: I've tried 4 or 5 settings here but still not working https://www.tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Tutti_gli_articoli_di_Marco_Crepaldi