# MediaWiki Semantic Template: Property "Title" (as page type) with input value

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

A few months ago I asked a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366858/mediawiki-semantic-template-property-as-page-type-with-input-value-contain) but the cause of the problem this time is different.

The error message is:

```
Property "Title" (as page type) with input value "Lo psicologo di base rischia di essere inutile se non ci sono abbastanza fondi stanziati

italianTitle = {{{italianTitle}}}" contains invalid characters or is incomplete and therefore can cause unexpected results during a query or annotation process.
```

[Here](https://www.tematichedigenere.com/index.php?title=Template:SemanticLink) I'm using an `{{#if` inside a template.
The property italianTitle is optional

```
<includeonly>[{{{url}}} {{#if:{{{italianTitle|}}}|{{{italianTitle}}}|{{{title}}}}}] - {{{tags}}} {{#subobject:
|url = {{{url}}}
|title = {{{title}}}

{{#if:{{{italianTitle|}}}|
|italianTitle = {{{italianTitle}}}
}}

|tags={{{tags}}}|+sep=,}}</includeonly>
<noinclude>
{{man}}

== Esempi:==

{{SemanticLink|url=https://www.instagram.com/p/CY_t7QhIWTD/|title=Lo psicologo di base rischia di essere inutile se non ci sono abbastanza fondi stanziati|tags=psicologia,governo,politica,lavoro}}

{{SemanticLink|url=https://www.instagram.com/p/CY_t7QhIWTD/|title=english title|italianTitle=italian title|tags=psicologia,governo,politica,lavoro}}
```

This MediaWiki template is used to create a semantic link, which is a link to a webpage with additional information (in a Semantic Mediawiki subobject) such as a title and tags.

The template has the following parts:

- The first part, `[{{{url}}} {{#if:{{{italianTitle|}}}|{{{italianTitle}}}|{{{title}}}}}]`, creates the link to the webpage specified by the "url" parameter. It also displays the title of the webpage, which can be specified by either the "title" or "italianTitle" parameter.
- The `#if` function checks if the "italianTitle" parameter is passed, if it is, it will be used as the title, otherwise, the title parameter will be used.
  The second part, `{{{tags}}}`, displays the tags associated with the webpage, which can be specified by the "tags" parameter.
- The third part, `{{#subobject:|url = {{{url}}}|title = {{{title}}}|italianTitle = {{{italianTitle}}}|tags={{{tags}}}|+sep=,}}`, creates a **subobject** which is a container for additional information related to the link. Here it contains the `url`, `title`, `italianTitle` and `tags` parameters. The `+sep=,` is used to separate the tags with a comma when they are displayed.
- The triple curly brackets, {{{ }}} , are used to define template parameters.
  When the template is used on a page, the text inside the curly brackets is replaced by the value passed to the corresponding parameter.

For example, the {{{url}}} will be replaced by the value passed to the "url" parameter when the template is used, {{{title}}} will be replaced by the value passed to the "title" parameter and so on.

Comment: The "if" part inside your subobject is wrong

Comment: The `{{#if:...}}` continues the `title` parametre. You have to put two variants of `{{#subobject:...}}`, with `italianTitle` and without, in an `{{#if:...}}`.